# Select child element in Inline styling ( Material UI makestyles )

Tags: material-ui, inline-styles

I'm using material ui makeStyles for styling and unable to select child element from style.js

style.css

```css
.item:hover > .subListItem {
  display: block;
}
```

When I changed it to inline styling, it isn't working.

style.js

```js
item: {
  "&:hover > .subListItem": {
    display: "block",
  },
},
```

Here's how I have applied classes

```js
<li className={classes.item}>
  <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.subListItem}>
    <ul className={classes.subItem}>
      <li>
        <Link to="/cs">COMPUTER SOCIETY</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/ras">RAS</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/wie">WIE</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </Paper>
</li>
```

What is the correct way to select child element in inline styling?

Comment: please also provide code how your classes are applied to JSX elements. I assume the problem here is that `.item` is a static class name, but `classes.item` is a dynamic one. The latter does not target `class="item"`

Comment: I have added the classes as className={classes.item}

Comment: And your static `item` class is gone entirely? This is impossible to debug without knowing the DOM structure and knowing what classes are applied where.

Comment: I have added the JSX code. Yes, I have removed the static class completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI class names are non-deterministic, please take some time to consult the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names) on what that means.

`classes.subListItem` does not result in a `subListItem` class being attached to the DOM element. You can also see this behavior by inspecting the element in the DevTools.

To make this work, you need a static class name:

```js
<Paper elevation={3} className="subListItem">
```

Some related notes:

*"inline styling"* refers to the use of the `style` attribute, which is not the case here. What you are doing is called CSS-in-JavaScript, or more specifically, JSS. You are still using the `class` attribute though.

The use of the child combinator can be tricky, as a single MUI component can result in multiple DOM elements and you might not always want to target direct children. Each component API will give you hints on how to change styles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful to understand how classes are added to DOM. But after seeing your answer I just used template literal and added a static class along with a dynamic one. `<Paper elevation={3} className={``${classes.subListItem} subListItem}``>` Is this approach correct, because I have added the static class same as the dynamic one

Comment: Generally speaking, there is absolutely nothing wrong with that. Your syntax is not correct though. For the case at hand, I would remove the class attribute from the `li` element and use `classes.sublistItem` along with `sublistItem: { "li:hover > &": {...} }`. Also take a look at the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) packages, which are incredibly helpful.